# How to Change Font Color based on Conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

When a User checks off :good in the **_form**

```
    <%= f.text_field :result_value %>
    <%= f.date_select :date_value %>
    <%= f.check_box :good %>
```

how can we render the font color in the index of that result (`:result_value` & `:date_value`) to green?

`result.good` below pulls up true or false in the index. I'll take that out once we represent true or false with colors: true = green, false = red (default color).

```
        <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
          <li>
            <%= result.result_value %>
            <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %Y") %>
            <%= result.good %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
```

.

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  default_scope { order('date_value DESC') }
  scope :good, -> { where(good: true) }
  scope :good_count, -> { good.count }
end
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the LI based on the output?

```
<% if result.good == true %>
    <li class="green">
<% else %>
    <li>
<% end %>
```

Then in your css just set a colour for that class?

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: `if result.good == true` can be shortened to `if result.good`, and since it is a boolean field, you can directly use `if result.good?` to return `false` if `result.good` is actually `nil`.