# How to use nested_attribute boolean to change font color in sidebar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

When a User checks off `:good` in the _form how can we render the font color green  of that result in the sidebar?

We made this work in the index: [How to Change Font Color based on Conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189726/how-to-change-font-color-based-on-conditional/29189940#29189940).

But the sidebar logic is making this trickier by rendering an additional quantified/result for every result when I tried this (we try to address this issue furthur here: [How to stop double rendering in sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549935/how-to-stop-double-rendering-in-sidebar)):

```
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
  <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
    <% if result.good == true %>
      <div class="green">
        <li>
          <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %> <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %> <%= averaged.metric %> <span class="label label-info"> <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %></span><% end %>
        </li>
    <% else %>
      <div class="red">
        <li>
          etc...
```

Current code:

```
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
  <li>
    <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %> <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %> <%= averaged.metric %> <span class="label label-info"> <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %></span><% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>

<% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
  <li>
    <%= instance.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b %d") %>: <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %> <%= instance.results.first.result_value %> <%= instance.metric %>, <%= raw instance.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

**application_controlller**

```
def set_stats
  @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
  @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged if current_user
  @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance if current_user
  @statsresults = current_user.results.stats if current_user
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

**quantified.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  has_many :results #correct
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
 scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
 scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }
  validates :categories, :metric, presence: true
 acts_as_taggable

 CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

**quantifieds controller**

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @quantifieds = Quantified.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :metric, :date, :comment, :private_submit, :tag_list, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :good, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**result model**

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  default_scope { order('date_value DESC') }
 scope :good, -> { where(good: true) }
 scope :good_count, -> { good.count }
end
```

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
  <div class="<%= result.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
```

In Rails, ActiveRecord will automatically define a method on each boolean fields, method which would always return either `true` or `false` (never `nil`):

```
# example
# User's boolean attribute 'is_admin' in the DB
# Rails will define an instance method called `is_admin?`:
User.new(is_admin: true).is_admin? # => true
User.new(is_admin: false).is_admin? # => false
User.new(is_admin: nil).is_admin? # => false
# the defined method's name is `<boolean_attribute_name>?`
```

---

Also you don't need to be explicit like this:

```
if result.good == true
  #etc.
end
```

You can just write:

```
if result.good
  #etc.
end
```

If `result.good` returns `false` or `nil`, it will not go into the if block. If it returns anything else than `false` or `nil`, it will execute the if block.

Comment: MrYoshiji to the rescue! But due to Mr. Galli's incompetence he is still stuck. Your code creates the same error I had before "by rendering an additional quantified/result for every result submitted". I don't think I'm writing it wrong. And thanks for the `==true` explanation.

Comment: This is because you `joins` the results to the Quantified, it duplicates the `quantified` records for each `result` associated with it. Use `Quantified.includes(:results)` instead

Comment: Using your code or taking it out made no difference. I'll just leave it out. But the issue remains :(

Comment: Can you post the source code of the scopes `averaged` and `instance`? Also, there is a flaw in your code: if there is no `current_user`, the 3 variables `@averaged_quantifieds` etc. won't be set, but in your view you call them directly without testing them : you will end up with a "undefined method .each for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I don't see why a `result` is being rendered twice. Your code seems okay, but your question is about how to use a boolean attribute to change the font color. Eventually create a new thread for the other issue of the double-rendering

Comment: I was going to wait to bring this up after we solved the double rendering because that was the more pressing problem, but `<div class="<%= result.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">` isn't changing the color to green or red. The font color is default black. Did I leave something out?

Comment: well you have to apply a proper css rule for every `div.green` with `color: #BADA55;` (for example) and `div.red`. Do you see the class in the HTML output when you inspect them? (inspect = right click on the HTML element + "inspect element" in Chrome)

Comment: Okay MrYoshiji I got your color code to work :) and based on your suggestion I'll continue the conversation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549935/how-to-stop-double-rendering-in-sidebar if you decide to attempt it or offer insight on how I can improve the question. Thanks again!