# How to stop double rendering in sidebar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rendering

The code is double rendering like so:

[image]

when it should just list it out once like so:

```
Ran 1 miles Apr 
Journal 1 days Apr
```

**views/layouts/_stats.html.erb**

```
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
<% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
  <div class="<%= result.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
    <li>
      <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %> <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %> <%= averaged.metric %> <span class="<%= date_value_label_class(result) %>"> <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %></span><% end %>
    </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**application_controller**

```
def set_stats
  @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged if current_user
  @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance if current_user
end
```

Results are a nested_attribute to Quantifieds.

**quantifieds_controller**

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @quantifieds = Quantified.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :metric, :date, :comment, :private_submit, :tag_list, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :good, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**quantified.rb**

```
    class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :results #correct
        has_many :comments, as: :commentable
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
        scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
        scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
        scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
        scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }
        validates :categories, :metric, presence: true
        acts_as_taggable

        CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
    end
```

**result.rb**

```
    class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :quantified
        has_many :comments, as: :commentable
      default_scope { order('date_value DESC') }
        scope :good, -> { where(good: true) }
        scope :good_count, -> { good.count }
    end
```

The issue came about when trying to introduce differing font colors for results. To make that possible I had to introduce these two lines which are causing the double rendering: `<% averaged.results.each do |result| %> <div class="<%= result.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">`

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explain more about the logic and the data stored.

A guess is that there's two records in `@averaged_quantifieds` and three in `averaged.results`.  It is hard to determine the desired results without knowing the data stored.

Note that you are only displaying the firsts records results (`averaged.results.first`) in the `<%= raw ...` line

Try

```
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>

  <div class="<%= averaged.results.first.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
    <li>
      <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %> <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %> <%= averaged.metric %> <span class="<%= date_value_label_class(result) %>"> <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %></span><% end %>
    </li>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**Edit:** My bad, I missed one `result` object (`<%= date_value_label_class(result) %>`) hiding in the rest of the line

Change `result` to `averaged.results.first` wherever applicable

```
<% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
  <div class="<%= averaged.results.first.good? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
    <li>
      <%= raw averaged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %><%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %> <%= averaged.results.first.result_value %> <%= averaged.metric %> <span class="<%= date_value_label_class(averaged.results.first) %>"> <%= averaged.results.first.date_value.strftime("%b") %></span><% end %>
    </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The data stored are two averaged_quantifieds and three results per averaged_quantified if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Your code is giving me: `undefined local variable or method 'result'` NameError in Pages#home

Comment: Yea I'm trying to only show the first result for each quantified. Sorry for the multiple comments you keep editing :)

Comment: Note the div line changed as well.  It has  `averaged.results.first`.  I think you only removed the loop you need to change the `result.good?` to `averaged.results.first.good?`

Comment: Maybe you just missed the `s` in `results` based on the error

Comment: Awesome! No prob I've been at this for hours. Thank you :)

Comment: Anytime.  Just quick notes, when you get an error about the object locate it and inspect where it is coming from.  For displaying the right data, try to print the values in console to visualize and see the data brought. This will help you debug quicker.  Good luck

Comment: Yea learning more about console has always been at the top of my coding to-do list :)